# how to do kmod-less FTP on "centos like" vps?

Tags: centos, ftp, vps

I have recently figured out that my VPS is running a distro of Linux that isn't exactly CentOS. It's CentOS in a OpenVZ/Virtuozzo container. For more information, see "[When CentOS isn't CentOS.](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/OtherSpins)" I would like to allow for FTP from behind my iptables firewall (FTP works fine when all rules are set to ACCEPT). Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information. For example: What does "isn't exactly CentOS" mean? What do your current firewall rules look like?

Comment: @jscott [When CentOS isn't CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/OtherSpins)

Comment: @WesleyDavid Thanks for that, I didn't realize there was a FAQ for CentOS-like branches.

Comment: Do you have trouble with both passive and active FTP or just passive? In the latter case, you need to open an additional port range in your ipTables (so, port 20, 21, and the passive port range). For example, in PureFTPd, there is a directive `PassivePortRange` which specifies which ports the FTP daemon will choose from - the range you specify here needs to be opened in iptables.

Comment: i am using vsftp is there also a way to specify ports

Comment: The port range is specified on vsFTPd with `pasv_max_port=xxxxx` and `pasv_min_port=xxxxx`. You also need `pasv_enable=YES`. Add a rule to ipTables matching whatever port range you specify in the vsFTPd config and you should be good to go - no kmods should be needed.

Comment: do i add that those to etc/vsftpd or etc/vsftp

Comment: By default, vsFTPd looks for /etc/vsftpd.conf (so you should put the directives there - check that they don't already exist though). It is possible, however, to override the default config location by passing a different file path to vsFTPd on the command line (which one of your init scripts might do).

Comment: @cyberx86 Make that an answer so that it can be marked as such for future readers. Fair warning: [I'll steal it from you before the evening is out.](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1886/how-to-handle-unanswered-questions-that-have-the-answer-in-a-comment-or-edited-i/1931#1931)

Comment: And this, my friends is reason #29481759284 that [FTP Must Die](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTP comes in two varieties - active and passive. With active FTP the server requires ports 20 (data) and 21 (commands) open - it is easier to setup on the server, but harder to setup for the client (since the server initiates a connection back to the client). Testing active FTP is sometimes a good starting point to determine if your server's firewall is the cause of your problems.

Passive FTP is typically more universally compatible since the connections are established by the client. However, it requires port 21 (the command port) and another high numbered port to be open (for data transfer). Most FTP servers will allow you to specify a port range that will be used for passive FTP.

See [this site](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html) for a good overview of the differences between active and passive FTP.

Kmods typically add features - by verifying that ACCEPT'ing all connections resolves your issue, you have largely shown that you do not need a kmod in this instance, but that there are simply some necessary ports that are blocked.

In your FTP config, setup the appropriate directives to define the passive port range that will be used, and then open these same ports in iptables, and you should be good to go.

PureFTPd:

There is a directive `PassivePortRange`:

```
PassivePortRange min_port max_port
```

vsFTPd:
There are two directives `pasv_max_port` and `pasv_min_port`:

```
pasv_max_port=xxxxx
pasv_min_port=xxxxx
```

You also need to enable passive FTP with `pasv_enable=YES`.

By default, vsFTPd reads the configuration from `/etc/vsftpd.conf` (so you should put the directives there - check that they don't already exist though). It is possible, however, to override the default config location by passing a different file path to vsFTPd on the command line (which one of your init scripts might do).

Once you have specified the necessary ports, you can add them in a single ipTables command with:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport xxxxx:xxxxx -j ACCEPT
```

(Note: FTP is exclusively TCP - you do not need to enable UDP)